# String interpolation in innerHtml in other component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a variable with string interpolation:

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a href="core/upload/link/table/key/{{data.key}}" target="_blank">{{data.name}}</a></div>`
```

This variable is in a parent component, and I need it in a son component, where "data" is generated.

So I just have:

```
                <div [innerHTML]="$any(col.cellTemplate) | safeHtml"></div>
```

but it's not working for the {{}}.

Thanks.

Comment: please reframe your question with more details if possible a demo in stackblitz with the actual issue and expected result!

Comment: yeah sorry, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nf5x5l?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Pass an ng-template from the parent and then you need to pass the variables on the child using context.

parent code

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
}
```

parent html

```
<hello>
  <ng-template #tpl let-data="data">
    <div>{{ data | json }}</div>
  </ng-template>
</hello>
```

child code and html.

```
import { Component, ContentChild, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let person of data">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tpl, context: {'data': data}">
  </ng-container>
    <span> {{person.name}}</span>
  </div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() stringParent: string;
  @ContentChild('tpl') tpl;
  data = [
    {
      name: 'Bob',
      age: 35,
    },
    {
      name: 'Mike',
      age: 36,
    },
  ];
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5vjmqs)

Comment: thanks but I don't want to display the "name" in the parent component, but the name of my data array in child. I updated the stackblitz without values not useful

Comment: @BaaLa Does this answer fix your issue?